# what happend to getRelatedIds in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I was using this function in 5.3 and now when I try to use it in 5.4 like this:

```
$post->tags()->getRelatedIds();
```

I am getting errors that function does not exist, I checked the documentation for 5.4 and it's not there anymore.

Anyone knows why this usefull function was removed and what I can do to get all ids from related model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4 and 5.5 the getRelatedIds is replaced by **allRelatedIds**.

```
$post->tags()->allRelatedIds();
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for reasons why it has been removed but if you know the primary key name ahead of time (i.e. all your tables have an `id` column) you can simply do

```php
$post->tags()->select('id')->pluck('id');
```

if you want a more generic way you'd need to jump through some hoops

```php
$related = $post->tags();
$post->tags()
    ->select($related->getQualifiedKeyName())
    ->pluck($related->getKeyName());
```

Comment: I believe adding a select is redundant, since Laravel's pluck code will only select those columns.  Looking at the code, you can see pluck calls `get([$column, $key])`

Comment: Fair enough and yet until 5.3 the framework's implementation [were using](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L590) both. It never hurts to be absolutely sure what you're fetching from the database.

Comment: I ended doing this: return $this->tags->pluck('id');